# Application error in Heroku while deploying from flask

Tags: git, heroku, procfile

[image]

this is the error i am getting, i even changed my Procfile. did `git status' , added and pushed again and still i am getting the same error. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is:

- a [a missing dependency of django-organizations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28552018/6309)
- a [wrong requirements.txt content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61829424/6309)
- a wrong [path for the Procfile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49364569/6309) (it should be on the same path as `manage.py`)

Since, in your case, you have a FileNotFoundError, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60592760/6309), make sure that file `Restaurant_reviews.tsv` is part of your repository.

Comment: thanks for this bro but i am using this in flask and there is just one file as app.py, there are no files as wsgi.py or manage.py but Procfile is in that the same path as app.py. requirements.txt seems okay but idk how to upload files on heroku. i have already pushed the whole folder on heroku.

Comment: @RajSingh OK. I would try and follow a tutorial like https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deploy-python-flask-app-on-heroku/ or https://stackabuse.com/deploying-a-flask-application-to-heroku/, just to check if that is working.